# How to prove: $\int d^3 x d^3 yf(|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|) \phi_1(\mathbf{x})\phi_2^*(\mathbf{x})\phi_2(\mathbf{y})\phi_1^*(\mathbf{y})>0.$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Can we prove the following claim?

For any real function $f(x)>0$ and any complex functions $\phi_1(\mathbf{x})$ , $\phi_2(\mathbf{x})$ such that the following integral has finite result, then
$$\int d^3 x d^3 yf(|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|) \phi_1(\mathbf{x})\phi_2^*(\mathbf{x})\phi_2(\mathbf{y})\phi_1^*(\mathbf{y})>0.$$ The range of integral is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If it's true, how to prove it. If false, give me an counterexample.

Comment: is the range of integration all $R^3$?

Comment: @tired Yes. the range of integration is $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: You can simplify the problem by reducing to a single free complex function as the integrand can be written $f(|x-y|) g(x) g^*(y)$ where $g = \phi_1\phi_2^*$.

Comment: This is to prove that exchange integrals have positive contributions to energy, no?

Comment: @user14717 Yes, it's a problem in my hw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding all functions in terms of their Fourier transforms $F(x) = \int \hat{F}(k) e^{-ikx}{\rm d}k$ and evaluating the integrals over $x$ and $y$ (which gives us $\delta$-functions) we obtain

$$\int f(x-y)g(x)g^*(y)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int |\hat{g}(k)|^2\hat{f}(-k)\,{\rm d}k~~~~\text{where}~~~g(x) = \phi_1(x)\phi_2^*(x)$$

which is guaranteed to be positive as long as the fourier transform of $f$ is positive $\hat{f}\geq 0$. For example for the special case $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}$, which is the case that most often occurs in practice (chemistry / physics), this is the case as $\hat{f}(k) = \frac{4\pi}{|k|^2}$.

A sufficient condition for the Fourier transform of a radial function $f = f(|x|)$ to be positive is that $|x|f(x)$ is decreasing. See for example E.O. Tuck ["On Positivity of Fourier Transforms"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-positivity-of-fourier-transforms/D232B9DEB4819E4D2FF17E8162B8B066) and [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194107/conditions-for-positivity-of-fourier-transform).